# Spring Data JPA Failed to create query for method

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I want to list an order like

```
select * from post
Order by created_date desc
```

And here is my code

```
//Mapper
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long postId;
    @NotBlank
    private String postName;
    @Nullable
    private String url;
    @Nullable
    @Lob
    private String description;
    private Integer voteCount = 0;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private User user;
    @Column(name="created_date")
    private Instant createdDate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Sub sub;
    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        if (this.voteCount == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.voteCount;
    }
    

}
```

```
//Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findByOrderBycreateDateDesc();
    List<Post> findAllByDescriptionContaining(String description);
    List<Post> findAllByPostNameContaining(String postName);
    List<Post> findAllBySub(Sub sub);
    List<Post> findByUser(User user);
    
}
```

```
//Service

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<PostResponse> getAllPosts() {
        return postRepository.findByOrderBycreateDateDesc()
                .stream()
                .map(postMapper::mapToDto)
                .collect(toList());
    }
```

I'm using Java Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA
I got some error like this

```
 Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.Website.Step2.repository.PostRepository.findAllOrderbycreateDateDesc()!
 Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.Website.Step2.repository.PostRepository.findAllOrderbycreateDateDesc()! 
 No property findAllOrderbycreateDateDesc found for type Post!
```

Can u guys help me! I think i was wrong in "findByOrderBycreateDateDesc". Thanks!
Sorry for my english. This is the first time i post my question.xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit the method like this:

```
List<Post> findAllByOrderByCreatedDateDesc();
```

As it looks the table column name and the instance name are different therefore you have to annotate the instance variable as show below:

```
@Column(name="created_date")
```

Comment: Thank you but it's still not working xD

Comment: Still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes sir . It still getting the same error

Comment: Dear i have updated my answer.

Comment: Dear i just update my question . I've just followed your aswer but it's not working!

Comment: Do you have github to have a look at everything done so far and try to find the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/top9xlee/reddit-clone
Here is my project. My project is following reddit-clone-springboot-angular in youtube.

Comment: im glad to hear your answer to find the solution . Cause my deadline is 7/3 T_T

Comment: Dear I checked your project and updated the answer try it and if woks don't forget to accept the answer. Good Luck.

Comment: I will wait for your reply. Thank for all, Sir.

Comment: Do not wait the answer is already there. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Im sorry my bad. Love u sir. It's working. I got some similar question and your ideal help me xD. Thank you Sir

Comment: Do not forget to hit the tick and accept the answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

Your method name seems to be off.
`findByOrderBycreateDateDesc()` should be `findByOrderByCreatedDateDesc()` with the property name starting with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest but i tried it before
```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.Website.Step2.repository.PostRepository.findByOrderByCreateDateDesc()! No property createDate found for type Post! Did you mean 'createdDate'?
```

Comment: Seems there is another typo. In the method you use "CreateDate" but the property is named "CreatedDate". I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But here is answer:
List<Post> findAllByOrderByCreatedDateDesc();